How does escaping work and what is being escaped in this command?
I've been staring at this batch script command for days trying to wrap my head around what is being escaped/passed/ignored.
powershell -Command "Start-Process powershell \"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NoExit -Command `\"cd \`\"%scriptFolderPath%`\"; & \`\".\%powershellScriptFileName%\`\"`\"\" -Verb RunAs"

I have tried launching sections of the command to determine which parts are escaped and passed, but am confusing myself further unfortunately. Hopefully someone smarter than me can clarify what basic fundamental or concept I'm missing.
I would like clarification for these portions:

What is the purpose of the first backslash used? Is it due to the space that exists after the word powershell, or to escape the double quotes?
For the second -Command instance, what does the cd command end up resolving as? Is the backtick escaping the backslash? Or is the backtick + backslash combination escaping the quotes?




What is the purpose of the first backslash used?

In PowerShell CLI calls from outside PowerShell, " chars. embedded inside a "..." command passed to powershell -Command must be escaped, typically as \", i.e. with a backslash - even though inside a PowerShell session it is `, i.e. the so-called backtick that serves as the escape character.

For the second -Command instance, what does the cd command end up resolving as?

Your second -Command instance (CLI call) is doubly nested inside the outer CLI call:

Immediately nested is a Start-Process call that uses a "..."-enclosed string as its (positionally implied) -ArgumentList argument, which must therefore be represented as \"...\"

Inside that Start-Process call's \"...\" argument, which is the list of arguments for the inner CLI call, more escaping is needed:

The inner CLI call's -Command argument inside \"...\" then requires escaping as `\"...`\" - note the ` before \", which ensures that Start-Process sees `"...`", i.e. an escaped "..." string embedded in its -ArgumentList argument. It is ` that is needed, because the Start-Process call is evaluated inside the PowerShell session created by the outer CLI call.

Embedding double-quoted strings inside `\"...`\" then requires yet another layer of escaping: the arguments for cd and & must then be enclosed in \`\"...\`\", so that the inner CLI call ends up seeing \"...\" on its process command line.





Tips for robustness:

While it may seem that a \ is missing after %scriptFolderPath% in your command line, Mofi points out that this may be by design, due to relying on the value of %scriptFolderPath% ending in \, as is the case when you use set "scriptFolderPath=%~dp0", for instance.

In cases where you cannot know in advance whether or not the value ends in \, you can use the following workaround: insert a space after %scriptFolderPath%, followed by \ so as to form a proper escape sequence (\`\"), and append .Trim(), so as to make PowerShell remove the artificially inserted space (which was put there to prevent a trailing \ from accidentally forming an escaped with the \ from the closing \`\"):
powershell -NoProfile -Command "Start-Process powershell \"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NoExit -Command `\"cd \`\"%scriptFolderPath% \`\".Trim(); & \`\".\%powershellScriptFileName%\`\"`\"\" -Verb RunAs"




To avoid edge cases with unusual file and directory paths that contain cmd.exe metacharacters such as & (e.g. foo & bar.ps1, it is generally advisable to avoid cmd.exe's up-front string interpolation (e.g., %scriptFolderPath%).

Instead, reference the cmd.exe variables of interest as environment variables on the PowerShell side (e.g., $env:scriptFolderPath), which has the additional advantage of not needing embedded quoting - see this answer for background information.

However, this is not an option in this case, because it is the inner Start-Process -Verb RunAs-launched powershell.exe process that would need to access these environment variables, but it doesn't see them (only the outer powershell.exe process does, because elevated processes do not inherit the caller's environment).

A workaround is to define helper PowerShell shell-only variables in the outer powershell.exe process (e.g. $scriptFolderPath) with the environment-variable values, which can then be used with PowerShell's - more robust - string interpolation in the "..." string passed to Start-Process:
powershell -NoProfile -Command "$scriptFolderPath=$env:scriptFolderPath -replace '[`$]', '`$0';$powershellScriptFileName=$env:powershellScriptFileName -replace '[`$]', '`$0'; Start-Process powershell \"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NoExit -Command `\"cd -LiteralPath \`\"$scriptFolderPath \`\".Trim(); & \`\".\$powershellScriptFileName\`\"`\"\" -Verb RunAs"


Note:

-replace '[`$]', '`$0' is applied to the environment-variable values in order to escape any ` and $ characters embedded in them, to prevent PowerShell's string interpolation from interpreting them.

Additionally, -LiteralPath is used with cd (Set-Location), to ensure that the directory path is interpreted literally rather than as a wildcard expression. The latter is what happens if you use the (positionally implied) -Path parameter, which is problematic with paths that contain [ and ] (e.g. Report[1].txt).








What is the purpose of the first backslash used? powershell -Command "Start-Process powershell \"-ExecutionPolicy
-- This is a rather sloppily written line of PowerShell with far too many escapes than is actually necessary. The first backslash does not need to be there at all. For example, this could be simplified like this: powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NoExit -Command "& '.\%powershellScriptFileName%'" -Verb RunAs
As you can see in the sample re-write above, there's no need to perform a "cd" or Change Directory in-line. Simply provide the path to the script file.


While it may not be a good idea to have scripts rely on a specific working directory, a given script may, so your command isn't equivalent.
With the chosen "..." quoting, given that the inner CLI call is nested inside a Start-Process call - which effects elevation of the inner CLI call via -Verb RunAs - the escaping in the original command line is necessary and correct.
While '...' quoting in nested calls can simplify things, it isn't generally robust in cd and & calls (at least not without additional, nontrivial effort), given that ' is a legal file-name character.
